# how to use a url to query a remote database for android?

Tags: android, database, url

I have been stuck at this for hours now. I would like to use a URL to query a remote database in android. Can any1 give me an idea on how to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a good website to answer this question:  http://p-xr.com/android-tutorial-how-to-parseread-xml-data-into-android-listview/. Use HttpGet instead of HttpPost.
All thanks to Mark for helping me out with this.

Answer (score 0):

There is no general way to tell this, as the URL itself depends on the database and the driver.
Basically you need a jdbc driver for the database that you put into your project first. The docs will then give you the specific details.

For Postgres, this could look like

```
jdbc:postgresql://<host>5432/<dbname>
```

Having said that: usually it is no good idea to do remote jdbc calls (if you can't guarantee that the app will only be used in the local lan) and you should do some abstraction and e.g. send the data around via http requests that carry payloads encoded e.g. as json or xml.

Comment: Lol.. Sorry.. I didnt understand wadeva u just said. I'm still noob towards url and database.

Comment: jdbc,json. My application requires me to retrieve data from a library database.

Comment: @Joel: Please update your question to give as much info as you have in order to be able to help you. What is a "library database"? The built-in sqlite?

Comment: I was given a URL to search in a library database which should give me a number of results. But I dunno how to use this URL to connect to the database and retrieve the results. That's my current problem now.